# Regex - Alphanumeric specific length and numbers greater zero

Tags: regex

i have to check if a string has the following requirements:

- Specific length of 7
- Alphanumeric are allowed
- Numeric values after alpha values must be greater than zero: 
  -- B000100 is ok
  -- B000000 is not ok
- Words can not begin the following chars:
  -- KZ, SA, SS, HJ, S, D

I already have built a regex pattern, but for the problem with Alpha values with following numbers greater zero i have problems:

**VALID**

A000001

AB00001

A100000

A100001

ABCABCA

GR00001

GR12345

**INVALID**

12345

A000001A

A0000012A

***A000000***

***GR00000***

***ABCAB00***

Regex Pattern: 
**^(?!^KZ)(?!^HJ)(?!^S)(?!^D)(?!0{7})[A-HJ-Z0-9]{7}$**

How to check this values?

***A000000***

***GR00000***

***ABCAB00***

Comment: Just with regex can be quite complicated. Are you willing to use something like perl or python?

Comment: If there can be multiple "numbers" in the pattern, like `A000B00`, where both numbers must be non-zero, this is going to be much too complex for a regex. Don't use one.

Answer (score 1):

This regex `^(?!KZ|HJ|S|D|([A-HJ-Z]+)?0+$)[A-HJ-Z0-9]{7}$` would do. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH5uB5/3)

What the regex does is after start of line ensure none of the following conditions match

- `KZ`
- `HJ`
- `S`
- `D`
- `([A-HJ-Z]+)?0+$` This one ensure you can't have 0 till end of line optionnaly with char before.

It's a modified version of your original negative lookahead, compacted with alternation for clarity.

Comment: Note that this regex will mark `0000000` as valid. Not necessarily a problem, as the question doesn't specify this, but thought it was worth highlighting.

Comment: This is a good approach, it works for all examples, but from the description it seems like A10000A is no match (always number in the end it seems), but your expression would match that.

Comment: @maraca The requirements are unclear on this part (char follow by number or mixed)

Comment: @Alec true, I've updated as the original regex would reject all 0